# Java ee timestamp json serialisation format

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, timestamp

Is there a way to define timestamp serialisation in restful webservices, so I can exclude time zone?

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Dto getById(@PathParam("id") Id id) { /**...**/ }
```

This produces json carrying timestamps formatted like this: **2014-12-14T16:29:52.416371+02:00**

and I need only: **2014-12-14T16:29:52.416371**

**EDIT**
ISO 8601 format would do fine instead

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jackson for your JSON serializer there are several ways of doing custom serialization. You can read more [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers).

One of the ways of doing it is to use `@JsonSerialize` annotation with a class that extends `JsonSerializer<T>`

Comment: I know jackson, but in this case serialisation will have to be done by hand, iside my method? Or I can plug jackson into javaee framework?

Comment: Yes you can configure your Jax-RS implementation to use Jackson for serialization. Just search for Jackson and Resteasy or Jackson and Jersey (or what ever you're using) and I'm sure you'll find instructions.

Comment: Where should I look? I have no clue

Comment: Please, take a look at my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528139/jax-rs-change-json-serializer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a serializer and JAX-RS implementation independent way if you implement a custom entity provider / MessageBodyWriter. See: [the JAX-RS user's guide section on this topic](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html)