# JAX-RS change json serializer

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, timestamp, jax-rs

I want to change my serializer to jackson, so I could change timestamp format, i tried like this:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonConfig
        implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConfig() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS,
                false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

and in ApplicationConfig :

```
    resources.add(com.rfid.server.helpers.JacksonConfig.class);
```

It didn't work, I still get timestamps formatted like his: **2014-12-12T17:52:33.35031+02:00"**

I tried debugging `JacksonConfig`, breakpoint comes to the constructor, but not `getContext` method

Comment: Not sure I follow. It sounds like you want dates returned in ISO8601, which it is returning since you disabled `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`. Is this not what you're looking to return?

Comment: I can imagine 2 different causes. 1) You have two different major version of Jackson. 2) Jackson isn't being used. For instance if you are in glassfish, MOXy is the default provider. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32678321/2587435)

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code of [ISO8601DateFormat](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/ISO8601DateFormat.java) and to the [ISO8601 utility class](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/ISO8601Utils.java), used by Jackson to manipulate dates in the ISO8601 format, the result that you're seeing is the expected result.

If you want to have a new format for the date, you should do something like:

```
objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The @aribeiro comment seems to be ok. You just have to change the data format according to your requirements.

Make sure you have the following dependency in your project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```