# How to configure Jackson in Wildfly?

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jax-rs, wildfly

I've got a Session Bean with the following method:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Path("/calculate")
@Produces("application/json")
public CalculationResult calculate(@FormParam("childProfile") String childProfile,
        @FormParam("parentProfile") String parentProfile) {
...
}
```

The returned CalculationResult cannot be mapped to JSON and the following exception occurs:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.test.UniqueName and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)...
```

How can I configure Jackson and its `SerializationFeature` in Wildfly?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> "How can I configure Jackson and its SerializationFeature in Wildfly?"

You don't need to configure it in Wildfly, you can configure it in the JAX-RS applciation. Just use a [`ContextResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) to configure the `ObjectMapper` (see more [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQJaxRs)). Something like

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    
    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
    
}
```

If you don't already have the Jackson dependency, you need that, just as a compile-time dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are using scanning to discover your resource classes and provider classes, the `ContextResolver` should be discovered automatically. If you explicitly registering all your resource and providers, then you'll need to register this one also. It should be registered as a singleton.

---

#### UPDATE

As @KozProv mentions in a comment, it should actually be `resteasy-jackson2-provider` as the artifactId for the Maven dependency. `-jackson-` uses the older `org.codehaus` (Jackson 1.x), while the `-jackson2-` uses the new `com.fasterxml` (Jackson 2.x). Wildfly by default uses The Jackson 2 version.

Answer (score 7):

Wildfly 9

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Java class

```
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SomePojo implements Serializable {
}
```