# How to set a custom Jackson ObjectMapper for Jersey 1.0 client

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jersey-1.0

I am using Jersey 1.0 http-client to call a resource and deserialize the response JSON like this:

```
Client client = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig())
ClientResponse clientResponse = client.resource("http://some-uri").get(ClientResponse.class)
MyJsonRepresentingPOJO pojo = clientResponse.getEntity(MyJsonRepresentingPOJO.class)
```

Now the response JSON has some new fields and I am getting following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "xyz"
```

How can I change jackson's deserialization-mode to NON-STRICT, so that it will ignore the new fields?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4486787/1756430

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To configure the `ObjectMapper` for use with Jersey, you could

1. Create a [`ContextResolver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310779/2587435), and register the resolver with the client.

   ```
   ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
   config.register(new ObjectMapperContextResolver());
   Client client = Client.create(config);
   ```
2. OR Instantiate the `JacksonJsonProvider` passing in the `ObjectMapper` as a constructor argument. Then register the provider with the `Client`

   ```
   ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
   config.register(new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper));
   Client client = Client.create(config);
   ```

   Note, if you are using JAXB annotations, you'll want to use the [`JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/master/json/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java)

To ignore the unknown properties, you can you set a configuration property on the `ObjectMapper`, as shown in the [link from Sam B.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4486787/2587435).  i.e

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

---

**EDIT**

I made a mistake in the examples above. There *is* no `register` method for the `ClientConfig` in Jersey 1.x. Instead, use `getSingletons().add(...)`. See the [API](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientConfig.html) for more info.

Comment: The ClientConfig class in the jersey-client-1.18.jar does not have a register() method...

Comment: Sorry, I'm so used to using Jersey 2.x. See the [Javadoc](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig.html). You should be able to use `getSingletons().add(...)`

Comment: from the above link to save you some clicking - in Jersey 1.x DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES is DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES