# How to configure RESTEasy to use the Jackson afterburner module

Tags: jackson, resteasy, jackson-modules

With large payloads, we are seeing that when JSON is converted to POJO, it is taking lot of time. Internally it uses Jackson. Was wondering if there is a way that we can configure RESTEasy to use Afterburner module which seems to better the performace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the `ObjectMapper` to be used. One way that can be done is through a `ContextResolver`, as see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310779/2587435). Then just register the module with the `ObjectMapper` (as seen in the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-afterburner)).