# How do I configure the jersey client to use the same json format that the server expects?

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

This is the json I need (generated by Ember, but works on the server):

```
{"customer":{"partyType":"jdo.party.model.Organization","name":"asdf"}}
```

This is the json I'm getting:

```
{"id":null,"partyType":"jdo.party.model.Company","name":"Test Company","firstName":"","lastName":""}
```

I need the jersey client to emit the correct json, and I'm not sure why.
The client code:

```
client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(JacksonFeature.class);
client.register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getGlobal(),true));
resource = client.target("http://localhost:8090/crm/api").path("/customers");
CustomerDto dto = new CustomerDto(null, "jdo.party.model." + type, name, "", "");
response = resource.request()
                .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.json(dto), CustomerDto.class);
```

The class I'm converting to json on both the client & server:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
@JsonRootName("customer")
public class CustomerDto implements Serializable {

    @XmlAttribute
    private UUID id;
    @XmlAttribute
    @NotEmpty
    private String partyType;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String firstName;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String lastName;

    public CustomerDto(Party party) {
        if (party instanceof Person) {
            partyType = ((Person) party).getClass().getCanonicalName();
            firstName = ((Person) party).getFirstName();
            lastName = ((Person) party).getLastName();
        } else if (party instanceof Organization) {
            partyType = ((Organization) party).getClass().getCanonicalName();
            name = ((Organization) party).getName();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format("Customer must be person or Organization.  %s was passed instead.",
                            party.getClass().getCanonicalName()));
        }
        id = party.getId();
    }

    @AssertTrue
    public boolean hasName() {
        return isNotBlank(name) || isNotBlank(lastName);
    }

    public String getPartyType() {
        return partyType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((partyType == null) ? 0 : partyType.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CustomerDto other = (CustomerDto) obj;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (partyType == null) {
            if (other.partyType != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!partyType.equals(other.partyType))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerDto [id=" + id + ", partyType=" + partyType + ", name=" + name + ", firstName=" + firstName
                + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomerDto() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomerDto(UUID id, String partyType, String name, String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.partyType = partyType;
        this.name = name;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's two things we need to accomplish:

1. Ignore null values in the DTO
2. Wrap the JSON object in a root value.

### 1. Ignore Nulls

#### *You could...*

The easiest way is to annotate the DTO with

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

This will tell Jackson to ignore null values. You will also need to make sure to pass `null` as the constructor values instead of `""` (which is not the same thing).

#### *You could...*

If you want to set this property globally, you could configure it on the `ObjectMapper`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

There are a couple ways we can register this `ObjectMapper` to be used in our application

1. Configure it in a `ContextResolver`, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310779/2587435). Then register the `ContextResolver` with the client

   ```
   client.register(new ObjectMapperContextResolver());
   ```
2. Configure the mapper with a Jackson provider instance

   ```
   client.register(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider(objectMapper, null));
   ```

### 2. Wrap JSON

Only one way I know, and that's to configure the `ObjectMapper`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

The actual value used is determined by your `@JsonRootName` annotation value.

See above for ways to configure the mapper to be used with the application.

---

Note, to keep support for Jaxb annotations, it's possible you need to register the [jaxb module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310779/2587435) with the `ObjectMapper`

```
mapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
```

This I am not sure of, as using the JacksonFeature, JAXB annotation is already supported. But I don't know if providing an ObjectMapper overrides that or not. Same with using the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider explicitly. So you may just want to test things out.

Comment: I went looking for configuration on the server side to wrap the json as I needed.. and missed the annotation configuration where i did the second options.  Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: @JimBarrows The one thing I wasn't quite sure about in your question, is why the server would expect the JSON to be wrapped, i.e. `{"customer":{ }}`. Normally it would just expect `{ }`. If you wrap it in the client, then you would need to unwrap it on the server, in which case, you could use `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)`. But if you did not have this in the first place, I wasn't sure why you would even need to wrap it on the client side.

Comment: As I said above. I had configured the server as peskillet has said.  I had forgotten that I had done it via java, as opposed to a config file.  Hence my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the partyType and name attribute in the JSON , the why are you annotating the other fields in the CustomerDto.java class

Comment: Edited to try and clear it up.  The working json is generated by Ember, and accepted by the server.  The not-working is generated from the DTO ( that does work on the server), by Jackson.