# remove null value field from apache cxf REST response

Tags: apache, rest, jackson, jax-rs, cxf

I'm using `apache-cxf 2.7.11` + `jackson (codehaus) 1.9.13` + `spring 3.5` in my REST services web-container. I was wondering what would be the best way to remove `null` value fields from REST responses.

For example: 
My response is now like this:

```
{
 "name": "MyName",
 "age": 10,
 "address": null
}
```

I want my response to be like this (the `address` field has been removed):

```
{
 "name": "MyName",
 "age": 10
}
```

I've read about `apache-cxf` interceptors and filters here:

- http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html
- http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html

and wondering what is the best practice? is there any configurable setting that I can change instead of implementing my own filer or interceptor class?

I'm using `beans.xml` file for configuration, thus I'm looking on how to config it all here, where my beans are:

```
<bean id="jaxrsRestJacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"/>

<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider">
    <property name="mapper" ref="jaxrsRestJacksonObjectMapper"/>
</bean>


<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>

        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>

</jaxrs:server>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

This is the answer I was looking for:

see the updated `beans.xml` file:

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
    <property name="serializationInclusion" value="NON_NULL"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider">
    <property name="mapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

on top of your POJO class. This would ignore the null fields for that one class.

Or you could configure the `ObjectMapper` so it would apply globally

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
```

If you go with the latter, you can pass the `ObjectMapper` as a constructor arg to the [`JacksonJsonProvider`](https://github.com/gawkermedia/jackson-patch/blob/master/src/jaxrs/java/org/codehaus/jackson/jaxrs/JacksonJsonProvider.java) or [`JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`](https://github.com/gawkermedia/jackson-patch/blob/master/src/jaxrs/java/org/codehaus/jackson/jaxrs/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java) ([whichever one you are currently using](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-Jackson))

---

**UPDATE**

You could also use a `ContextResolver` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310779/2587435), and register the `ContextResolver` like you would any other provider. This will work better more complicated configurations. You might want to do that instead. With the `ContextResolver`, you don't need to configure the `ObjectMapper` with the `JacksonJsonProvider`, but you still do need the `JacksonJsonProvider`.

Comment: should this work recursively on objects? e.g. I have a list of Person class

Comment: Without testing, I'll just say that I would imagine so (at least with the ObjectMapper route). Have you tried it?

Comment: yes it is working recursively on objects as expected. Your answer helped me find the exact values I had to set in my xml configuration file. I posted an answer with the xml file configuration.

Comment: You could also use a ContextResolver as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28310779/2587435), and register the ContextResolver like you would any other provider. This will work better more complicated configurations. You might want to do that instead. I was going to add it to my answer but got lazy :-) With the ContextResolver, you don't need to configure the ObjectMapper with the JacksonJsonProvider, but you still do need the JacksonJsonProvider

Comment: Another option is to just extend the JacksonJsonProvider and you can configure the ObjectMapper in the constructor. The less xml the better :-)