# How to configure JsonPArser features in XML

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, cxf

I want to disable the CANONICALIZE_FIELD_NAMES feature and wanted to know how can I do that through xml http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd. For example I would configure the providers as follows

```
<jaxrs:providers>
   <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
</jaxrs:providers>
```

I assume the features would also be configured in a similar fashion

```
<jaxrs:features>
   ----
</jaxrs:features>
```

I tried checking online did not find any solution

Comment: Add an `ObjectMapper` bean and construct the `JacksonJsonProvider` with it.

Comment: So it cannot be done through xml ?

Comment: You _can_. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31637849/2587435)

Comment: Ok we cannot do it using <jaxrs:features>.If not what is the use of this element ?

Comment: What is it about that code I linked to that makes you think you cannot?

Comment: No I asked the question because the example sets the feature as a property of the ObjectMapper and does not use <jaxrs:features> element.So my original question was how can we add features using features element.I can obviously set the property on the ObjectMapper through Spring beans schema but since I am using the jaxrs xml schema I wanted to know how to do it using features.I hope this makes sense

Comment: Just add the JSON provider into the feature list like you are currently doing? JAX-RS know nothing about ObjectMappers, so there is nothing you can configure in a JAX-RS way. You just need to add the configured ObjectMapper to the JSON provider, and register the provider with JAX-RS like you are currently doing.

Comment: Or you can forget all this stuff, and use a ContextResolver instead (and configure the ObjectMapper programmatically). For that look at the link at the bottom of my answer in the same post. You can register the `ContextResolver` also as a JAX-RS provider.

Comment: As far as the features XMl element, this is reserved for JAX-RS [`Feature`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/package-summary.html). You _could_ configure the JSON provider programmatically inside a `Feature`, and register it there. And then register the `Feature`. There's a few ways you can do this.

Comment: Thanks more clear now