# How do you enable MOxy on WebSphere Liberty without breaking Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, jax-rs, moxy, websphere-liberty

Is there a way of creating an application using MOXy on WebSphere Liberty which uses Jackson and does not support JAXB by default for their JAX-RS implementation without breaking Glassfish or creating a separate build for WebSphere Liberty?

Comment: Jackson does support JAXB annotations. For JAX-RS, it comes in the form of the `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`. If you can figure how configure that, you can try to [configure the `ObjectMapper`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307646/how-to-configure-jackson-in-wildfly/28310779#28310779) with the [JaxbAnnotationModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations). I don't work with Websphere, so I can't give you any definite answers. Just a couple things you can try.

Comment: it used to work with the older glassfish, but they had switched to MOXy by default and WebSphere Liberty is using an older version of Jackson as well.

Comment: I don't know why you are referencing Glassfish? Are you referencing the actual server or the just Jersey 2x. in general? Also older version, you can still register JAXB annotation support module with ObjectMapper. See [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations)