# java how to override jackson ObjectReader?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

I'm writing rest services using jersey and jackson. I have something like [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)

```java
import com.mkyong.Track;

@Path("/json/metallica")
public class JSONService {

   @GET
   @Path("/get")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Track getTrackInJSON() {

       Track track = new Track();
       track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
       track.setSinger("Metallica");
       return track;
   }

   @POST
   @Path("/post")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public MyResponse createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

       return new MyResponse().setResult(true);
   }
}
```

But in my case, the classe Track is not a simple pojo bean.I use a Map to save my data and I create a method to generate json from my object and a constructor to parse json data.

```java
public class JsonObject {

    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    public String toJson(){
        return "";
    }
}
```

```java
public class Track extends JsonObject {

    public Track(String json) {
        //Parse json
        // [...]
    }

    public Track(JsonNode node) {
        //Parse node
        // [...]
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        if(data.containsKey("title"))
            return data.get("title");
        return "";
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        data.put("title", title);
    }

    public String getSinger() {
        if(data.containsKey("singer"))
            return data.get("singer");
        return "";
    }

    public void setSinger(String singer) {
        data.put("singer", singer);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Track [title=" + getTitle() + ", singer=" + getSinger() + "]";
    }

    public String toJson() {
        return "{\"title\": \"" + getTitle() + "\", \"singer\": \"" + getSinger() + "\"}";
    }
}

public class MyResponse extends JsonObject {

    public boolean getResult() {
        if(data.containsKey("result"))
            return (boolean) data.get("result");
        return false;
    }

    public MyResponse setResult(boolean value) {
        data.put("result", value);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{\"result\": " + getResult() + "}";
    }
}
```

So my question is: is it possible to create actions before and after  the method call to tell to jackson how to generate or parse my object  ?  using annotation and/or creating an ObjectReader or something like that ?

Thanks

---

Edit :

Thanks peeskillet.

I'm not sure  @JsonAnyGetter et @JsonAnySetter are my solution. I have many objects that extend JsonObject and I want to keep it with getters and setters for my rest api.

So I created a generic JsonSerializer:

```java
public class MyObjectSerializer extends JsonSerializer<JsonObject> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(JsonObject value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        gen.writeRaw(value.toJson());
    }
}
```

Then I add this annotation to MyResponse object.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyObjectSerializer.class)
public class MyResponse ...
```

I wish I did not have to add this annotation in each objects and that was done automatically during rest service return but it works fine and it's not so restrictive.

Now I have another problem with deserialization. I want a generic deserializer calling constructor with parameter JsonNode.  But how do I know what class call?

I saw a parameter "as" in @JsonDeserialize annotation.

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyObjectDeserializer.class, as=Track.class)
```

But I don't find how get this information in the JsonDeserializer. Any idea ?

(Maybe I could open another thread for this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

For the serialization,  I created a serializer for my JsonObject I defined in a contextResolver.  All classes that extend JsonObject are serialized using this serializer.

```java
    public class MyJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<JsonObject> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(JsonObject value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

            gen.writeRaw(value.toJson());
        }
    }


    @Provider
    public class JacksonJsonProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

        private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

        static {
            MAPPER.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
            MAPPER.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
            MAPPER.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        }

        public JacksonJsonProvider() {

            SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("SimpleModule", new Version(1,0,0,null, null, null));
            simpleModule.addSerializer(JsonObject.class, new MyJsonSerializer());
            MAPPER.registerModule(simpleModule);

        }

        @Override
        public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
            LOGGER.debug("JacksonProvider.getContext() called with type: "+type);
            return MAPPER;
        }
    }
```

For deserialization, I use the annotation @JsonCreator() to indicate to jackson what method used to create object.

```java
    @JsonCreator()
    public JsonObject(JsonNode json) {
        super(json);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To configure Jackson in JAX-RS, you can register a [`Context-Resolver<ObjectMapper>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html), as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310779/2587435). You can create custom serializers if you need to.

For your specific use case posted above, something as simple at using [`@JsonAnyGetter`](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureAnyGetter) would work without doing any other crazy stuff. [`@JsonAnySetter`](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html) for *deserialization*.

```
public class JsonObject {

    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void put(String field, String value) {
        data.put(field, value);
    }

    public String toJson(){
        return "";
    }
}
```

Jackson will serialize all the data in the map, as if they were properties in the class or subclasses. So you don't need to add any properties in the `Track` class.