# UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE not working jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I send an HTTP request to the server with content body in JSON form as follows.

**CLIENT**

```
String json = null;

            objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.SerializationConfig(Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE. true);
            objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new LongNameShortNameNamingStrategy());
            objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new SerializingAnnotionIntrospector());
            json = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);;

            System.out.println("CONVERTED JSON CONTENT" + json);

                HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                ( (HttpPut) httpUriRequest).setEntity(entity);
                System.out.println("ENTITY" + entity);
```

This converts my content into JSON and adds root element too. I use a naming strategy to convert my property names in a form and similarly use `AnnottaionIntrospector` to convert rootName into same form.

```
{
  "ae" : {
    "api" : "THA",
    "aei" : "",
    "rr" : false
  }
```

The root element in Annotation was `AE` which was converted to `ae` inside `AnnotationIntrospector`, similarly keys are shortened using `PropertyNamingStrategy`.

**SERVER**

```
@PUT
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public void handlePutRequest(Object resource) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setDeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new LongNameShortNameNamingStrategy());
        objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new DeserializingAnnotionIntrospector());

    objectMapper.convertValue(resource, AE.class);
```

The resource which is recieved on the server is `LinkedHasMap` of the JSON sent from client.

```
 CONTENT: {ae={api=THA, aei=, rr=false}}
```

As one can see the modified root name is present.

However, `objectMapper.convertValue(resource, AE.class);` is not converting it into `AE` POJO correctly and gives the error:

```
resteasy-servlet threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Root name 'ae' does not match expected ('AE') for type [simple type, class cdot.onem2m.resource.xsd.AE]
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
```

I have applied `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`, but still it's giving error. I guess `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` works only on a Json string ??

If from cliemt I don't wrap root value and send json like,

```
{api=THA, aei=, rr=false}
```

without root element
 I can successfully convert resource to POJO (using `objectMapper.convertValue(resource, AE.class)`).

But it's not working after wrapping. Any suggestions for this??

Comment: Have you tried to just use a String parameter in your resource method, instead of Object?

Comment: @peeskillet: You mean recieve content in method like   `public void handlePutRequest(String resource) {` ???

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28310779/2587435), if you want to configure the unwrap globally. This way you can just accept the `AE` parameter, instead of explicitly deserializing it in every method

Comment: @peeskillet: Using that gives a JSONstring, but the exception is there:  `"ae" : {
  "api" : "THA",
 "aei" : "",
"rr" : false
  }
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Root name 'ae' does not match expected ('AE') for type [simple type, class cdot.onem2m.resource.xsd.AE]`

Comment: Try adding `@JsonRootName("ae")` onto the class, see what happens

Comment: I cannot edit my POJO. It's a generated one. My POJO has `@XmlRootElement(name = "AE")`. Thus I use `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`, to serialize root element from `AE` to `ae`. Now either I can revert it back or unwrap root. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure. It's out of the scope of my knowledge :-(