# JAX-RS: serializing a POJO fails on payara micro

Tags: glassfish, jax-rs, jackson2, payara-micro

After moving our application war from Glassfish3 to a deployment with Payara Micro, the JAX-RS serialization (jersey + jackson) doesn't work any more.

Thanks to [Adam](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jax_rs_returning_a_list), we solved the issue with serializing pure collections, we now encounter similar errors when returning POJOs:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public BirdyTO findAllDaBirdy() {
    return getBirdy();
}
```

where BirdyTO is a POJO which contains other POJOS and/or collections of POJOS.

That one gives us the error:

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json;charset=utf-8, type=class org.example.BirdyTO, genericType=class org.example.BirdyTO.
```

Strange thing is that similar interfaces in same application work fine.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked that the .war contains all of the needed jackson dependencies? And could you add the BirdyTO Class code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping of POJOs to JSON is not standardized in Java EE. Glassfih 4/Payara use MOXy to map POJO to JSON by default, which uses JAXB for the mapping. See [this post by Reza Rahman] (https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/moxy_is_the_new_default). It is possible that BirdyTO cannot be mapped by Moxy.

If you want to use Jackson, you have to:

- disable default Moxy feature (by setting `jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson` property to `true`)
- add Jackson library into your app (`com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs`)
- turn on the JacksonFeature (provided by the Jackson library) in your JAX-RS application

More info how to do it in this answer: [Customizing JSON marhsalling with GlassFish v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054821/customizing-json-marhsalling-with-glassfish-v4)

Comment: Gold info and correct solution. Thanks a lot! Still don't know why MOXy fails to map some POJOs, but I guess we should stick to jackson since we built our app with it in the first place.

Comment: We got it. Obviously MOXy requires the transport POJOs to have default constructors.

Comment: In Java EE 8, the mapping should be standardied by the JSON-B specification. Until then, the behavior differs in subtle differences like this. Please mark the answer as the correct anwser :)